# lazy loading image with progress bar make image corruption when the image displayed

Tags: java, android

I have an application the displays images from server . now i lazy load my images . 
so initially i display a progress bar when the image finish loading i remove the progress bar by setting it `visibility` attribute to `View.INVISIBLE` and the image appears . This is the layout file i use for images

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loading_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**The problem** 
When the progress bar disappear the image displayed on screen but corrupted . like this image

when i refresh the list the images loaded from the cache directory and when they displayed on screen they display correctly without any corruption .

[image]

ImageLoader class i use to  lazy load image

```
public class ImageLoader {
    // @@ JUST FOR THIS PROJECT
    BaseAdapter mAdapter;
    // @@
    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;

    boolean addRoundCournerAndStroke = false;
    boolean scale = false;

    boolean localfile = false;
    int default_image;

    public ImageLoader(Context context, boolean flag, boolean scale,
            boolean localfile) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
        this.addRoundCournerAndStroke = flag;
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        this.scale = scale;
        this.localfile = localfile;

    }

    public ImageLoader(Context context, boolean flag, boolean scale,
            boolean localfile, int default_image_id) {
        this(context, flag, scale, localfile);
        this.default_image = default_image_id;
    }

    public ImageLoader(Context context, boolean flag, boolean scale,
            boolean localfile, int default_image_id, BaseAdapter adapter) {
        this(context, flag, scale, localfile);
        this.default_image = default_image_id;
        this.mAdapter = adapter;
    }

    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            changeProgressBarVisibilty(imageView, false);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        else {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(this.default_image);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = null;
        if (localfile)
            f = new File(url);
        else
            f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        // Log.d("bytes", "decode");
        // from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null)
            return b;

        // from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;

            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();

            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            // //Log.d("bytes", "decode");
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private Bitmap decodeFileWithoutScaling(File f) {
        try {
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = 1;
            //o2.inPurgeable = true;
            if (this.localfile)
                return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), o2);
            else
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null,
                        o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {

        if (this.scale) {
            return decodeFileWithScalling(f);
        } else {
            return decodeFileWithoutScaling(f);
        }
    }

    // decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFileWithScalling(File f) {
        try {
            // decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        //  o.inPurgeable = true;
            if (this.localfile)
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), o);
            else
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            // Log.d("width", width_tmp + "");
            // Log.d("height", height_tmp + "");
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        //  o2.inPurgeable = true;
            // Log.d("after shave width", o2.outWidth + "");
            // Log.d("after shave height", o2.outHeight + "");
            if (this.localfile)
                return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), o2);
            else
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null,
                        o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad)) {
                return;
            }

            Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);

            // if (addRoundCournerAndStroke) {
            // // bmp = ImageHelper.rotateAndFrame(bmp, 10);
            // bmp = ImageHelper.getRoundedCornerBitmap(bmp, 10);
            // }

            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            photoToLoad = p;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            changeProgressBarVisibilty(photoToLoad.imageView, false);
            if (bitmap != null) {
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


            } else {
                photoToLoad.imageView
                        .setImageResource(ImageLoader.this.default_image);

            }
            if (mAdapter != null) {
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
    }

    private void changeProgressBarVisibilty(ImageView image, boolean visible) {
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) image.getParent();

        try {
            View v = layout.findViewById(R.id.loading_layout);
            v.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }



    }



    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library for image loading. Maybe it hasn't this problem.

Comment: Instead of hiding the progressbar, when image loads, make the imageview visible. Hide  it before starting to load...

Answer (score 5):

Try to use ProgressDialog instead of Progressbar. ProgressDialog also can use Progress bar. ProgressDialog is not XML type. so you can show() or dismiss() method. Maybe it hasn't this problem.
I think this problem come from RelativeLayout. If you use ProgressBar Visiblity , RelativeLayout still visiable(but has no background). Also RelativeLayout has any item. I guess Empty layout was gave you corruption. 
Using ProgressDialog is Best..

Answer (score 3):

The corrupted image shows damaged-JPEG artifacts.

Your problem may arise from the  `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` method. Not all JPEGs are optimized for on-the-fly decoding ('progressive') so they maybe need to be available as a whole before beeing decoded correctly. Usually, non-progressive images can be decoded top-down, but that maybe doesn't hold for all files or the decoder may have some flaws that prevent that.

On the other hand, if the image is later fetched from the cached file, `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` is used which doesn't need to care about streamed data and can randomly access the image file to decode the JPEG. If you don't need the  line-by-line display updates while loading the image, I would suggest to eleminate this code path and allways download the whole image before decoding.

Comment: I had similar problems with on the fly-decodings, as well. storing them first as temporary files solved the problems.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try to set visibility as `View.GONE`, because when you set `View.INVISIBLE` the View still holds the place, and like Tae said it can be some issues with RelativeLayout.

Cheers